# Is there any point in flagging duplicates asking the mod to merge the answers?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-answers

I have two such flags still in the active state, one dating from the 4th Jan.

If the mod are deciding to take no action as they don’t consider this to be worth their time, then I will save their time by not flagging these.

Comment: I was recently told that flagging is the correct way to request a merge, after which I raised a flag. I just noticed though that the same request was made [over 3 years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript#comment3525405_27509) and nothing has happened since, so I'd also like an answer to this.

Comment: @Stijn that's probably an extreme case (ironically, Robert's diamond confuses the comment as I don't think he was a mod when he posted that comment).

Comment: My understanding is that merging posts is a very manual process as it  so it takes time, and it means the mods needs to know they will have a sufficient amount of time when they start working on it.

Comment: Does anyone know how many of these flats are just sitting about?

Answer (score 3):

Only diamond moderators can merge questions. Merging two questions moves all the answers from the source question to the target question, the source question is deleted 30 days later automatically. The whole thing is an irreversible process (at least for a diamond moderator), and can only be undone manually by an SE developer.

We moderators tend to be careful about merging as we can't easily undo any mistakes, so if there is any doubt I won't merge at all.

Flagging fro moderator attention is the correct procedure if you think that two questions should be merged. But I would make sure that merging is really the best course of action here before flagging. If there is any doubt about whether the closure as a duplicate was correct, merging is unlikely to happen. Merging also only makes sense of you actually move some really good answers, moving some mediocre answers to a question that already has better ones is a waste of time. But if there is a good answer on the closed question and no answer or only worse ones on the open one, flagging for merging is the best course of action.

I won't speculate on why your flag is still open on SO as I can't see the details there.

Comment: I do not like “the source question is deleted 30 days later automatically” as it may still be of use to people goggling, to point at the “master” question.

Comment: Would it be better for me to write my own answer on the “master” question, based on the answers on the duplicate question, so calming all the rep for myself, but saving the mods the work?

Comment: @IanRingrose - I'd also add that these flags asking for merging of duplicates (or closing things as duplicates) hang around a lot longer than others due to the fact that unless the wording is identical between the two, a moderator who's a subject matter expert will have to review it. For example, I saw your flags and deferred handling them to someone else because I don't know the technologies involved. I'd rather have them sit there for a little longer than make a bad (and possibly irreversible) call.